# Loading new data to a C3.js line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'm trying to dynamically update a C3.js line chart using a function that get a set of x and y values from a database. The function I'm trying to use to insert the data is:

```
function insertGraph(yAxis, xAxis, Header) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("starting");
        chart.load ({
            bindto: "#graph",
            xs: {
                'y':'x'
            },
                columns: yAxis, xAxis   
        });
    }, 100);
}
```

The data being passed into the function looks like this:
yAxis:

`["y", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`

xAxis:

`["x", 0, 131.35, 26971.3, 27044.75, 27351.4, 27404.483333333334, 27419.416666666668, 33128.96666666667, 33549.13333333333, 34049.48333333333, 77464.26666666666, 77609.71666666666, 174171.85, 259166.98333333334]`

Header:

`MakeModeChange #just a string`

I know I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here, but any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs it I managed to figure out my issue. It's all in how you do the "columns" portion (it need to be bound in `[]`). Here's the fixed code just in case:

```
function insertGraph(yAxis, xAxis, Header) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        chart.load ({
            bindto: "#graph",
            xs: {
                'y':'x'
            },
            columns: [
                yAxis, 
                xAxis
            ]   
        });
    }, 100);
}
```